# How to release the resource of the used HttpRequest and HttpRespone

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

All, Usually if we want to release the resource of something like `Connection` or `Stream`. we have to call the method like `close()` to make that in Asp.net. 
But I don't find any method of `HttpWebRequest` like `close()` to let Asp.Net to release the resource.
So, Commonly if I want to use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpWebResponse` , the code snippet kind like this way . Please review below. Is there anything wrong with it ? I am not sure about that . Thanks.

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = createGetHttpRequest(detailModel, RequestServiceType.GetToken,null);

    string returnedContent = string.Empty;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                returnedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        //  string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        response.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Write(e);
}
```

Comment: I see no problem , as you have used using , then asp.net manages it itself . it sounds correct afak . one thing I can suggest as not good is try/catch . catching exceptions just to log it is not good to be done here , instead use ELMAH or other logging frameworks

Comment: @mohsen.d Doesn't need to manage the `request` life-cycle?

Comment: you can use using with request too .